# How to execute "Stored Procedure" Query in node-oracledb if we are not aware of stored procedure bind parameters?

Tags: node.js, oracle, stored-procedures, node-oracledb

All the examples in documentation were given with bind variables.But what if, we are going to execute the query(Stored Procedure) which has written by the user.(In this case we will not be aware of what are all the input and output parameters to bind).
I am able to execute all the basic ddl and dml queries. But how to execute stored procedure like queries and what will be the way of retrieving?

Will there be any luck if we use "db-oracle"?

Note: I am new to nodejs and node-oracle-db

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following examples:

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlfunc.js
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/plsqlproc.js

Also, I don't understand why you would not be aware of the input and output parameters to bind to. It would have to be a VERY dynamic situation for that to be true. It would be similar to saying: we don't know the names of the columns of the table we need to query. I'm not saying it doesn't happen or that there aren't unusual circumstances where this could be an issue, just that it's highly unusual.

In either case, whether you don't know the inputs and outputs of stored procedures or even if you don't know the names of the columns, that's where data dictionary views come in. Try running the following queries to begin exploring the views that may be relevant to you:

For procedures:

```
select *
from all_procedures;
```

For arguments:

```
select *
from all_arguments;
```

Comment: I am not aware of parameters in the sense, I am trying to develop a web application like oracle sql developer tool. So what ever the user writes, I need to just execute it. In this case How would i know parameters? Do i need to parse the query at backend??

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand your problem... You don't need to know about parameters. The user is writing it, they will know about parameters. You just need to provide a means for them to specify the parameters. I think the missing piece to your puzzle is DBMS_SQL. This is the PL/SQL package that you'll need to execute dynamic code like you're trying to do.

Comment: Can u please provide me an example to understand, if you got my problem.So that i will try it. I am actually new to oracle also.

Comment: I am able to execute basic ddl and dml queries using node-oracle-db. But coming to pl-sql queries like procedures functions, It seems: To get out put i need to bind out params and type. But , How is this possible when we are executing queries what ever the user writes. Do i need to parse the query to find procedure name, and parameters?? I think it would be heck right?

Comment: I think you need to design the system so that the user that is supplying the code also supplies the binds (names, types, etc.).